# Fusible resistor blowing on flyback converter

Tags: power-supply, flyback, circuit-protection

I have a flyback converter circuit with AC input, and I have a fusible resistor on the hot line before the rectifier. When I hook up AC power to the input, the fusible resistor immediately blows. It does not matter what load I connect, this happens in all load conditions. I am using a 10 Ohm, 3W resistor, the DC output is designed to run at 6 W. The voltage rating on it is 120 V AC (RMS).

I know the circuitry on the secondary side is working and there are no shorts, I was able to bypass the transformer and apply DC power, and I can see the correct DC output.

Anyone have any ideas on the cause of the problem? Is this as simple as choosing a different fusible resistor or is there something else I should do that can provide the same kind of circuit protection?

Circuit is shown below. R1 is modeling the fusible resistor. The datasheet link is: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/54/fw-777661.pdf
The fusible resistor is 10 Ohm, 3W. When I simulate the voltage drop across R1 I find that it is +-400 mV

[image]

Comment: Please post schematic and oscillograms of primary side.

Comment: Do you have a schematic? Do you have an adjustable DC power supply? Do you have a scope? Suggest using the DC supply (with a current limit set to, say, 0.5A) to supply power to the suspect circuit (the flyback), and slowly bring the voltage up from 0 while monitoring the flyback output with a DMM, and monitoring primary switch voltage waveform with a scope. Post the results.

Comment: We need to know voltage and design current in and power out AND fuse TYPE and rating. || Is this a converter that you have built and/or designed? Is it new or did it work previously or ... ? || Plce yourself in out position - without knowing these and perhaps other things we can only guess. Please provide as much relevant information s possible.

Comment: @FabioBarone I do have a scope but the problem is that the fusible resistor immediately blows regardless of the current limit I set and the load I put on the output, so I can't capture any measurement. I don't have a DC supply that can provide equivalently high DC input (such as if I bypass the rectifier). I'll get a schematic and add it.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The fusible resistor ratings and power out are provided in the question. Current in would be 35 mA based on power conservation on each side, so that would amount to 12 mW of power being dissipated on the fusible resistor on average. The converter is based on a reference design with a TI flyback controller. That's why this is so strange, I do not see why with such low average power the resistor should blow. If it is due to switching in the flyback controller drawing current spikes into the resistor I could see large instantaneous power being a problem...

Comment: @sparaps  If your scope is digital, then get a single-shot trigger on the first turn-on edge of the main primary switch.  Capture 4 traces: 1. primary switch voltage, 2. its gate voltage, 3, Vin, & 4. Vout, over a period of about 10 to 20 normal cycles of operation, eg: if Fs=100kHz (10us period) then capture 20 cycles = 200 microseconds.  

And as for blowing the fusable resistor with such low average power: if there is a large capacitor storing energy from the AC supply, then that would have more than sufficient energy to thermally damage the resistor.

Comment: @sparaps  Your comment "that the fusible resistor immediately blows regardless of the current limit I set ".  What current limit are you referring to here, that of your external DC power supply, or the flyback with the problem, or something else?

Comment: @sparaps  It appear that my brain and eyes did not comminicate when I read that :-). Sorry. || Link to reference design AND your circuit would help. || If there is an input cap charged at turnon it could easily account for what you see. || Not likely here, but an inductor will draw maximum current if switched into circut at the zero crossing. I plugges in an isolatring transformer tonight and it tripped a local 10A breaker. Subsequent multiple plugging ins did not do so.

Comment: @sparaps  This questuon was closed by 3 members votes (not mine) for "needs details or clai]rity". || This question can be reopened if somewhat more infomtion is povided. I suspect that a charging capacitor is the cause BUT I don't have enough information to be sure. || You say that it is a TI reference design. Please say so in the questjonAND provide a link, Please advise how your implementation varies. Please advise fuse rating and type and ideally data sheet link. ||

Comment: @RussellMcMahon this is reopened with more details, see above. The reference design is generated from Webench and it matches the above circuit.

Comment: @sparaps THanks. I reopened it about an hour ago (two others had aleady voted to reopen). I had not yet got to comment as follows. Extra information is good, thanks. Could you please provide a link to the reference design. I looked at various related data sheet, app note and reference designs and but not find an identical one. || Importantly - do any have a fusible link resistor of that rating plus a 10 uF or similar capacitor at C7. This seems ample to blow the fuse. ...

Comment: The fusing performance graph in page 3 [here](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/54/fw-777661.pdf) suggests that the instantaneous power in the resistor is far above rated fusing current due to capacitor inrush.

Comment: In your simulation try starting Vin at sinewave peak rather than at zero time. || Interest only: A few days ago I had a contactor trip once when a transfomer was connected ti an outlet but successive conneections failed to trip it. (Inductors take peak current if connected at zero crossing)(perhaps non-intuitively).

Comment: Connecting a scope ground to the primary will pop the fuse.  
Try removing the transformer and seeing if the fuse can charge up the capacitor.  C7

Comment: @RussellMcMahon What I am reading from your comment about fusing performance is that the fuse is blowing because the input is pushing a maximum inrush current of 17 A, so the instantaneous power dissipated in R1 would be 2.89 kW, thus fusing time gets very low. This would mean a bigger resistor would be needed, correct? Or should I try eliminating the input capacitor C13?

Comment: @sparaps  (1) **PLEASE** provide a link to the TI reference design. (2) Do TI use a 10 Ohm 3 Watt fusible link in the input? (3) Have you tried just charging the capacitor via the fusible link.  || The actual instantaneous current will depend on cap ESR, wiring resistance and inductance, and more. But it sems likely that the fusible link is being stressed beyond it's design limits. You can test this by (i) link + cap only as above. (ii) Add a much larger series resistor (say 100 Ohms to 1 k), charge cap and then short the extra R with a clip lead (with due care). Odds are it will then work OK

Comment: @RussellMcMahon there is no link, it was generated from Webench, which is TI's online reference design generator for power systems. TI did not use a fusible link at the input. I tried without the fusible link and the rectifier blew instantly on power up, which is odd because the rectifier is rated at 600 V.

Comment: @sparaps  "Something is wrong" !!! :-( :-). || NC is shown as "not internally connected" BUT grounding it MAY not be wise. || Mot likely seems to be that the reference and actual circuit differ. Is this in a PCB or ??? ||. I trouble shoot by - checking that all connections that should exist do exist (continuity beeper). || - Checking that connections that should not exist dont - continuity beeper between all adjacent pins. And between all adjacent track-track and pad-pad and pad-track. || - Is eg opto polarity at in and out correct? - || Are resistir valuesd as intended - measure them. || ...